# Adding values based on the user's input in array basis

Tags: c, arrays, sum

I'm stuck with this code:

```
int main()
{
    int a[ ] = {0};
    int n,sum = 0;

    printf("Enter your element: ");
    scanf("%d", &a[n]);

    while(n != -1)
    {
        sum = sum + a[n];

        printf("Enter your element: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }

    printf("The sum is %d", sum);
}
```

My aim is to make a prompt to user to enter his value that will be stored in the elements of the array, then give him the sum of the values that he entered.

However the code does not show any error, but it ends up giving garbage value.

Comment: If you don't get any compiler warnings for this code, then please check that you have enabled them.

Comment: This is a good time to start using debugger. Problems like these can often be solved with it easily.

Comment: Why store the elements in an array if all you want is to calculate the sum?

Comment: @user694733, you get no warnings with `scanf("%d", &a[n]);`? `n` is uninitialized at that point invoking *Undefined Behavior* when it is accessed as the index for the array. Second `int a[ ] = {0};` a one element array??? Using gcc minimum warnings would be to include `-Wall -Wextra` in your compile string, with clang `-Weverything`, with VS (`cl.exe`) using `/W3` should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int a[100] = { 0 };   // array of 100 numbers all initialized to 0
  int sum = 0;
  int n = 0;

  do
  {
    printf("Enter your element: ");
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number);

    if (number == -1)
      break;

    a[n] = number;
    sum += a[n];
    n++;
  }    
  while (1);

  printf("The sum is %d", sum);
}
```

Disclaimer: There is no error checking, and there is no check if you entewr more than 100 numbers which results in an index out of range problem.

Comment: It was helpful mate.. Thanks

Comment: @Someone_having_Interest yes, please accept the answer that you think helped you most  by clicking on to the outlined green check mark. You can also upvote the answers that you think are useful.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d", &a[n]);` accessing array index out of bound if `n!=0` this is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

And `n` is uninitialized. So using that as an index is using as index in the array some indeterminate value.

`while(n!=1)` is not an exhaustive check. better would be `n==0` as the array has only 1 element.

Maybe you wanted this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{

    int n;

    printf("Enter no of element: ");
    if( scanf("%d", &n) != 1){
        fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in input");
        exit(1);
    }
    if( n <= 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"Enter positive number of elements");
        exit(1);
    }
    int a[n];
    int sum = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if( scanf("%d",&a[i]) != 1){
            fprintf(stderr,"%s","Error in input: give integers");
            exit(1);
        }
        sum+=a[i];
    }

    printf("The sum is %d", sum);
}
```

<sup>Notice that this program has the following flaws which is difficult to overcome with `scanf()` - you can try to modify over this using `strtol` and `overflow-checking`</sup>

1. If user inputs something other than this range `[INT_MIN,INT_MAX]`, thre will be overflow. (Soln: Use `strtol`)
2. Sum can overflow given any large inputs whose sum is not in this range.
   (Overflow check:

   ```
   if ((a[i] > 0 && sum > INT_MAX - a[i]) || (a[i] < 0 && sum < INT_MIN - a[i]))
   {
       fprintf(stderr,"%s","Sum has overflown");
       exit(1);
   }
   ```

Comment: @Someone_having_Interest you can also *accept* an answer. ;)